# Android Studio Flutter Tooltips Not Showing

Tags: android-studio, flutter, ide

I am following along a tutorial for Flutter using Android Studio. The instructor's screen shows more detailed tooltips / hints than my environment does.

I am unsure of how to enable these extra details.

**Examples**

Instructor's Screen (*extra tooltip details in red*):
[image]

My Screen
[image]

Answer (score 8):

Go to Preferences->Editor->General->Code Completion

Check the box "Show the documentation popup in xxx ms"

Answer (score 5):

After having the Basic Code Completion open (Control + Space), then hit Control + Q (Win/Linux) or Control + J (Mac) to open the Quick Documentation Lookup, this will make your screen appear as your instructors. Alternatively, just hit the last keyboard shortcut to only see the Quick Documentation Lookup.

For more keyboard shortcuts see: https://developer.android.com/studio/intro/keyboard-shortcuts

Comment: For me, it worked, but it didn't show automatically i.e. without Control + Q. It is opened automatically when user types few words and select respective entry from tooltip in the video tutorial I am learning from.